# Backbone model not sending data on SAVE

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-model

This is the way I'm populating the attribute of my model:

```
this.model.set('questionAnswers', arrQuestions);
```

Now on submit, I check if model is valid:

```
 if (this.model.isValid()) {
                this.model.save(null, { success: this.gradingQuestionsSuccess, error: this.gradingQuestionsFailed });
            }
```

Validations works like this:

```
validate: function (attr, options) {
            var error = null;

            if (attr.questionAnswers.length < this.cntQues) {
                this.trigger('empty:answers');
                error = 'Please answer all the questions.';
            }
            return error;
        }
```

And service call is:

```
 url: function () {
            var url = Application.getConfig("url") + "/";
            url += Application.getConfig("v2path3") + "/account/submitGradingQuestions";
            } 
            return url;          
        }
```

The model is valid and the values are set in it on Submit, but it's not sending it in the Request Payload.

[image]

Can anyone please help me understand why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Backbone does not observe the changed attributes and sync on `save(null)` automatically. What you need is pass attributes to `Model.save` method that makes `set` under the hood [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L621) or [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L636) depending on `wait` option's property. So you just need the following:

```
var data = {questionAnswers: arrQuestions};

this.model.save(data, {
   success: this.gradingQuestionsSuccess,
   error: this.gradingQuestionsFailed 
});
```

You also don't need invoke validation manually because it's get invoked in [save method](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L623) also.